# Can I delete data from firebase without knowing the unique key ID using unity3d c#?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know if there's a way of deleting data from firebase realtime-database without knowing the unique key id that is generated on the `push()` method. When I save data to the database I'm currently using this to delete the data:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("people").Child(name.text).RemoveValueAsync();
```

The problem I have with this, is that if I don't know the unique id I can't delete the data and I need to find a way to delete the data without knowing the unique id.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the best solution but after 2 weeks of working on this-this is my best solution... when I add the data I'm using the name.text string to be the unique key id

```
    public void AddScore()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(sales.text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(stock.text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(date.text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUsed.text))
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Check Inputs");
             return;
    }

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("people");

    Debug.LogWarning("Adding Customer...");
    if (reference != null)
    {

        Dictionary<string, object> newScoreMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        newScoreMap["customer"] = customer.text;
        newScoreMap["sales"] = sales.text;
        newScoreMap["stock"] = stock.text;
        newScoreMap["date"] = date.text;
        newScoreMap["newUsed"] = newUsed.text;

        reference.Child(name.text).SetValueAsync(newScoreMap);      
    }

}
```